# How can I make my android app work online?

Tags: android

This is most likely going to get downvoted into oblivion but I seriously cannot find an answer and I don't know where to begin...

I have just finished developing a chess app but its purely offline, ie, you can only play with some one sitting right next to you.

I want to make this app online, as in, I can connect to my wifi, click **match me with an opponent**. And start a game with some else on my app?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html

Comment: @rciovati Thank you so much, I will read it.

Comment: Follow the many samples on making online android games [here](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/android-game-developers-home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i know Some will downvote this question But 
Follow these links

[1.Android multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer)

[2.Tick tak two multiplayer](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-androidtictactoe/index.html)

[3. Multiple player Andengine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/611201/Make-realtime-multiplayer-AndEngine-games)

[4.How to make multi player](http://www.indieflashblog.com/how-to-create-an-asynchronous-multiplayer-game.html)

or check [this](https://code.google.com/p/mages/)

hope this will help you..

Comment: and also follow Yannic Welle answer that may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) and [Client/Server models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).
What you basically need is a way to build a data connection between your players. Lets say I am Player A and I open a chess-server-socket on my phone and want you to join it. Problem here would be, that I as a default user lack a way to tell you my nonstatic IP address to connect to. So I need you as a developer to provide a blackbox that does all this for us.